# Computing a matrix in numpy by function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have function that assigns a feature vector of fixed length `n` (1d numpy array) to an object: `feature_vector(obj)`.

I also got a function that computes the dot product of the feature vectors of 2 obejcts (A whole function just for dot product is unnecessary...i know. But I think it will get more complicated than a dot product in the future):

```
def kernel(obj1, obj2):
    return return np.dot(feature_vector(obj1), feature_vector(obj2))
```

Now i get a list of `m` of these Objects, and want to compute a matrix for the repective kernels:

```
def computematrix(objlist):
    m = np.zeros((len(objlist), len(objlist)))
    for i in range(len(objlist)):
        for j in range(len(objlist)):
            m[i][j] = kernel(objlist[i], objlist[j])
    return m
```

Is there a more efficient /mory pythonic /more numpy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do all that in a single line:

```
m = [[(kernel(objlist[i], objlist[j]) for j in range(len(objlist))] for i in range(len(objlist))]
```